# How do I recreate a UIImage at a lower compression in iOS?

Tags: ios, image-processing

I have code to recreate a high quality image at a very poor quality but I am a bit confused by the results I am seeing.  The code is here:

```
NSData *compressedData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bigImage,0);
NSLog(@"compressedData length = %d", [compressedData length]);
self.currentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:compressedData];
NSData *dataAfterCompression = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.currentImage,1);
NSLog(@"dataAfterCompression length = %d", [dataAfterCompression length]);
```

Which outputs:

```
2012-01-02 02:47:05.615 MyApp[349:707] compressedData length = 32671
2012-01-02 02:47:06.143 MyApp[349:707] dataAfterCompression length = 251144
```

Why would creating a new image with the low quality data result in such a large image?

Answer (score 9):

The input to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is a 2-D array of pixels, not the compressed data from which that 2-D array was created.  (The array might not have come from compressed data at all!)  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` doesn't know anything about where the image came from, and it doesn't have any concept of the "quality" of its input.  It just knows that you want it to try very hard to make the output small (when `compressionQuality` is zero) or you want it to try very hard to make the output accurate (when `compressionQuality` is one).

The JPEG compression algorithm has some tunable parameters.  The `compressionQuality` value selects a set of those parameters.  When you set `compressionQuality` to 1, the compressor uses a set of parameters that allow very little loss of accuracy of the input data, regardless of what that input data actually is.  For *any* input data, those parameters result in very little loss of accuracy.  The tradeoff is that those parameters also result in very little compression.  The compressor doesn't then think "Hmm, I should try using other parameters and see if I get the same accuracy with better compression".  If that's what you want, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: The input to UIImageJPEGRepresentation is a UIImage, not a 2-D array of pixels.  My question is really asking how constructing a UIImage with 32671 bytes of data could result in a UIImage the size of 251144 bytes.  I'm guessing it's because creating the UIImage decompresses the data and expands it to fill out the entire UIImage (although I would think it would need a frane to do this) and also that compressing the image data really doesn't save much space.  I was looking for a more technical description of why this is happening.

Comment: JPEG is an algorithm for compressing 2-D pixel arrays.  So when you call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, it asks the `UIImage` for its 2-D pixel array, and operates on that.

Comment: Maybe my question is confusing but this really doesn't answer my question at all.  Obviously that method is going to ask for the pixel data.  That's not the input to the method but sure, to compress image data, it will ask for the data :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this blog has some classes that extend UIImage and it deals with compression quite nice. Check out this website:
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: How does it deal with compression "quite nice"? Sorry, I only see image resize code there

Comment: In the classes titled UIImage + NSCoding, there is some code that deals with coding format and quality, I though that it might help point in the right direction about compression, but perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem